# How to authenticate index page using spring-security

Tags: java, spring-security

In my application I want to authenticate index page so in context I add:

```
<!-- Security -->
<security:http create-session="never" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="hasRole('MY_ROLE')" />
    <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
</security:http>
```

this works ok when I go to adress: http://localhost:31103/my_app/index.jsp

problem is when I enter adress http://localhost:31103/my_app/ which redirect to index then there is no autentication. So how should I authenticate these case too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `intercept-url pattern` value to `"/"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting user to index page when user enters  http://localhost:31103/my_app/ redirect him to login page then check if user is already authenticated if yes redirect him to index page.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
    Authentication auth=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if(!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)){
        model.setViewName("redirect:/index");
    }

    return model;
}
```

Comment: I have no login page. I am using basic authentication

Comment: @hudi try to put index page in new folder, lets call that folder admin, and then set security like this  `<security:intercept-url pattern="admin/*" access="hasRole('MY_ROLE')" /> `

Comment: sory I cant move index page